# Who was Thor referring to when he said "or a genius"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, avengers-infinity-war

During the conversation between Thor and the Guardians of the Galaxy Thor began explaining his perspective of Thanos' quest for the Infinity Stones. He then told them that he (Thanos) must be going for the Reality Stone and that it's with a man called the Collector. Peter Quill then says that if it's with the Collector then it's not safe only an idiot would leave the stones with the Collector. It is at this this point that Thor says "or a genius". Who was Thor referring to?

Comment: I'm 100% sure that it wasnt the warriors 3 (or Volstagg & Sif to be exact) because they clearly look like they were sent to the Collector. My money is on Odin.

Comment: Answer: Thor. See [Thor: The Dark World](https://youtu.be/K1imOiVCgYM) (Post credit scene 1).

Comment: There's no help in the novelisation.

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly himself. Thor has control over the Reality Stone and the Warriors Three/Lady Sif are his friends, allies and warriors. They would take the Stone there if he wanted them to.

You also have to remember that Loki had put Odin under a spell and taken his place at the end of *Thor: The Dark World*. It wouldn’t be like him to send the Reality Stone away so it was almost certainly Thor who did that.

And of course the scene in *Avengers: Infinity War* is a boasting match between Peter and Thor. Peter is saying it is stupid and foolish to give a Stone to The Collector; an attempt to get a dig at Thor and also a joke about them almost doing it. Thor retaliates saying it is a genius idea because no one would expect the Asgardians to hand it over to The Collector. You also have to remember The Collector specialises in collecting and keeping things safe: he would do his best to do that and keep it out of Thanos’ hands.

Comment: I disagree. Thor left asgard at the end of TDW. And yes technically odin was exiled whilst loki was on the throne, odin (or loki I should say) was the one calling the shots.

Comment: @Ericallday Well it wasn’t Odin, Thor left after he was replaced. It doesn’t fit Loki’s MO to give away the Stone. That only leaves Thor and in the context of the argument Thor saying it about himself makes the most sense. Thor could very easily have left a message to his friends to take the Stone there or the scene just isn’t shown chronologically.

Comment: I agree was assuming that it was possibly Loki.